# How to implement foreign composite key between two table when part of FK key are already in primary key in hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem implementing my tables in my Java code with Hibernate / JPA.

I have two dependent tables:

```
Table A
-------
FieldA1 (PK) Date
FieldA2 (PK) String
FieldA3      String
...

Table B
-------
FieldB1 (PK) Date
FieldB2 (PK) String
FieldB3      String
...
```

My two tables are linked by two foreign keys:

> FieldA1 / FieldB1

> FieldA3 / FieldB2

I am looking to do a query on the two tables (starting from table A) to obtain all the fields from table A and field B3 from table B.

I created the Entities Below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
public class TableA implements Serializable {

   @EmbeddedId private TableAId id;

   @Column(name = "field_a3")
   private String fieldA3;


@Embeddable
public class TableAId implements Serializable {

   @Column(name = "field_a1", nullable = false)
   private String fieldA1

   @Column(name = "field_a2", nullable = false)
   private Date fieldA2
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
public class TableB implements Serializable {

   @EmbeddedId private TableBId id;

   @Column(name = "field_b3")
   private String fieldB3;


@Embeddable
public class TableBId implements Serializable {

   @Column(name = "field_b1", nullable = false)
   private String fieldB1

   @Column(name = "field_b2", nullable = false)
   private Date fieldB2
}
```

I can't implement ForeignKeys between the two tables with @OneToOne because part of the join key is already in @Embeddable Key

The request I want to execute :

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM TableA a, Table b WHERE b.field3 = :mycode ")
```

Do you know how I can do it?

**UPDATE 1 - Adding OneToOne test**

```
        @MapsId("FieldA1") <- KO
      @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "FieldA1", referencedColumnName = "FieldB1"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "FieldA3", referencedColumnName = "FieldB2")
      })
@OneToOne
```

When I build, I have this message

> Could not locate field name [FieldB2] on class [java.util.Date]

Comment: you might want to revisit your statement that you cannot use a OneToOne, as you certainly can. Check out JPA derived IDs, specifically the mapsId annotation. For a query though, your example request is only returning A instances and doesn't show a join. Did you try something like "SELECT a, b.fieldB3 FROM TableA a JOIN TableB b ON b.id.fieldB1 a.id.fieldA1 AND b.id.fieldB2 = a.fieldA3" with your current model?

Comment: Thx, With your resquest (INNER JOIN) it's OK but I can't get tableB.fieldb3 value in my entity. How can I map it ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'in my entity'. Which entity, and why would you do that? Are you looking at having one entity that spans both table_an and table_b, or just An instance of TableA that has a reference to TableB (if the later, see my comment regarding using a OneToOne and give details on exactly what you think isn't possible, as there are a number of ways to do it depending on how you want to use it in the application). Otherwise, the query I gave will give you TableA instances with the fieldB3 data that you can put in any java object you want.

Comment: I try to use @MapsId but I can't because my relation OneToOne links TableA and TableB with 2 FK which one is on the PK of TableA (FieldA1 as Date)
I can't define multiple MapsId on my OneToOne Relation (I have update my post)

Comment: MapsId is meant to let JPA control setting the FK values from the relationship, but you don't need MapsId to make it work. Just mark the join column fields as read-only and continue to control the fk values through your basic properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A can be mapped a number of ways. One with the least amount of changes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
public class TableA implements Serializable {

   @EmbeddedId private TableAId id;

   @Column(name = "field_a3")
   private String fieldA3;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumns({
     @JoinColumn(name = "FieldA1", referencedColumnName = "FieldB1", insertable=false, updatable=false),
     @JoinColumn(name = "FieldA3", referencedColumnName = "FieldB2", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   })
   private TableB b;
}
```

You will still need to set TableA's fieldA3 and id.fieldA1 properties for the fk columns to be set.